# Can Python's Pandera validate whether a Geopandas DataFrame has Linestrings

Tags: python, geopandas, pandera

Is there a way to check data types other than the standard built in data types (str, float, int)? I tried the following, but that results in an error, because the data type LineString is unknown to Pandera. Any suggestions?

```py
import pandera as pa
from shapely.geometry import LineString


class Schema(pa.DataFrameModel:
   id: int = pa.Field(unique=True, nullable=False)
   geometry: LineString = pa.Field(nullable=False)



try:
    Schema.validate(some_df, lazy=True)
except pa.errors.SchemaErrors as err:
    errors = err.failure_cases
    error_data = err.data
```

pandera extensions as a possibility? How to implement then?

Comment: import geopandas as gpd  # You'll need this library for Shapely types

Comment: that is not true. The shapely types come from the shapely package

Comment: solution is given at https://github.com/unionai-oss/pandera/issues/1208